# C# display specific data to users based on username

Tags: c#, .net

I am designing a C# application where users will only have access to data he inputted and to do this I am getting his username on the login page. The application works well locally because only one username enter at time. But when I deployed it on the server to be tested the following happen: when many users log in and if one of them insert his data, after inserting for the page to be updated in order to display new entered data I execute a query where  I check again his username, but at this time the variable that holds the username will have been updated by the username of the last user to log in and this result by displaying data of the last user!!!
Please assist me on how to implement this, except this error everything is working fine.

```
    private void loadgridview()
    {
        try
        {
            string a1 = login.a.Text;//getting username from login page
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM EXPENSES WHERE INPUTTER='" + a1 + "'ORDER BY E_ID DESC", con);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(table);
            GridView2.DataSource = table;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            SqlDataAdapter da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(E_ID) from EXPENSES WHERE INPUTTER='" + a1 + "'", con);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da_1.Fill(dt1);
            counter.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() + "  RECORDS";
            SqlCommand mg = new SqlCommand("select dbo.increment_ID()", con);
            EX_ID.Text = mg.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use session, to keep the login details and then fetched details from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

ie

```
private void Login(string username, string password)
{
    // Your login logic

    // Set the session if login was okay
    Session["loginUsername"] = username;
}
```

then

```
private void loadgridview()
{
    try
    {
        string a1 = Session["loginUsername"]; //getting username from session

       // ...
```